# node.js + mongoose + HTTP PUT Not Working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, http, mongoose

I'm following [scotch's](http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/easy-node-authentication-setup-and-local) tutorial, so I have this user schema:

```
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({

    local            : {
        email        : String,
        password     : String,
    },
    facebook         : {
        id           : String,
        token        : String,
        email        : String,
        name         : String
    },
    twitter          : {
        id           : String,
        token        : String,
        displayName  : String,
        username     : String
    },
    google           : {
        id           : String,
        token        : String,
        email        : String,
        name         : String
    }

});
```

I'm trying to make a http put to update some data with x-www-form-urlencoded, but I'm not able to set the fields, this is what I have:

```
PUT /teacherup HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

email=example%40gmail.com&password=randompass
```

How can I make an appropriate http put and set those fields? I would also like to know how to do this with JSON.

-- Update with put

Here's the http put:

```
app.put('/teacherup', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
        if(req.user.usertype == 1)
        {
          util.updateDocument(req.user, userschema, req.body);
          req.user.save(function(err) {
              if (err)
                  throw err;
          });
          res.send(200, {message : 'Teacher saved!'});
        }
        else
        {
          res.send(406, {message : 'Not a teacher!'});
        }
    });
```

-- Update methods for saving doc

I'm using these methods for updating a doc

```
exports.updateDocument = function(doc, SchemaTarget, data) {
    for (var field in SchemaTarget.schema.paths) {
       if ((field !== '_id') && (field !== '__v')) {
            var newValue = getObjValue(field, data);
            console.log('data[' + field + '] = ' + newValue);
            if (newValue !== undefined) {
                setObjValue(field, doc, newValue);
          }
       }
    }
    return doc;
};

function getObjValue(field, data) {
    return _.reduce(field.split("."), function(obj, f) {
        if(obj) return obj[f];
    }, data);
}

function setObjValue(field, data, value) {
  var fieldArr = field.split('.');
  return _.reduce(fieldArr, function(o, f, i) {
     if(i == fieldArr.length-1) {
          o[f] = value;
     } else {
          if(!o[f]) o[f] = {};
     }
     return o[f];
  }, data);
}
```

Comment: Big deal. Where is the controller code?

Comment: just updated with the http put

Comment: Nothing to do with Rep score. Just quality of question. `req.params` is kind of a standard in all web frameworks. You never even searched the web for "express request params" did you? This is the kind of response you should expect from your boss when you ask.

Comment: You want to update previous document or save the current one? If you clear this I will try to help you.

Comment: I'm trying to update a previous document, just updated with the methods I use

Answer (score 0):

I am showing you the server side code for inserting a new document using 'express' and 'mongoose'. Hope this will helps you.

```
var app = require('express)(),
    mongoose=require('mongoose'),
    userModel=mongoose.model("user", userSchema);
app.put('/teacherup', update);
update=function(req,res){
     new userModel
        .save(object)//I have not created the object you have to create it according to yourschema 
        .exec(function(err, result) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                console.log("Successfully inserted");
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: Tell you what.If you update this to explain what the OP is doing in their functional code is wrong and how to properly do it here then you get my upvote. And fairly quickly since that is only fair and you have yet failed to do so.